# facebook graph API calls limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

When I run my application the API calls reaches their limit so fast. Any solution to extend the total number of calls?
[image]

Comment: without knowing exactly what you do, it is impossible to give you an answer, i am afraid

Comment: i'm trying to get metrics from facebook and instagram pages with node js and react js, i can fetch all the necessary metrics via node js but when i try to consume the API calls via react js the application reach the limit of calls so fast from first or second call. Can i demand from facebook to extend the number of the API calls

Comment: again, i am afraid you have to be a lot more specifics. include the relevant code. extending the api call is most likely not an option, but maybe you are doing something wrong anyway. like, doing api call you could combine, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the number of api calls are limited; you can find info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/).

Althought you cannot extend the number of calls, you can still manage the way to do a call. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/) you can find the Facebook best practice but I suggest you to:

1. Split the call in order to ease the load
2. Do asynchronous requests
3. Try to filter the data you are not interested to